Zoom with Command Key and Scroll Wheel Not Working as Expected on Reactflow
The documentation states that 'zoomActivationKeyCode' defaults to Meta, which corresponds to the Command key on Mac. However, scrolling with the wheel to zoom doesn't work as expected; instead, it requires Control + Scroll Wheel. What's wrong here? I want to zoom using the Command key and the scroll wheel. Why is this so difficult to achieve?
<ReactFlow
    panOnScroll={true}
    onlyRenderVisibleElements={false}
    zoomOnDoubleClick={false}
    zoomOnScroll={true}
    zoomOnPinch={true}
    draggable={false}
    panOnDrag={true}
    snapToGrid={true}
    preventScrolling={false}
    nodesDraggable={IsPreviewOnly ? false : true}
    panOnScrollSpeed={1}
    ref={ReactflowRef}
    style={styles}
    nodes={Nodes?.length > 0 ? Nodes : NoNodes}
    edges={Edges}
    nodeTypes={nodeTypes}
    onMove={OnPlaygroundMove}
    proOptions={{ hideAttribution: true }}
    maxZoom={ZOOM_LEVELS.MAX}
    minZoom={ZOOM_LEVELS.MIN}
    onPaneClick={OnPanClick}
    selectionOnDrag={true}
    zoomActivationKeyCode='Meta'
    onInit={(r) => OnPlaygroundInit(setReactFlowInstance, r)}
    onEdgeClick={(e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        e.stopPropagation()
    }}
    onNodeContextMenu={(e, n) => OnNodeContextMenu(
        e, 
        n,
        ReactflowRef
    )}
/>

